# How does one use KNN to predict something in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, classification, knn

How do we use KNN to make predictions?

When we see examples of KNN algorithm (e.g.: [k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm (k-NN) in the Iris data set](https://www.kaggle.com/xvivancos/knn-in-the-iris-data-set#introduction) and [Introduction to k-Nearest Neighbors: A powerful Machine Learning Algorithm (with implementation in Python & R)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-k-neighbours-algorithm-clustering/)) the algorithm is not being used to predict anything. My question is: let's suppose a have the [iris dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/arshid/iris-flower-dataset) (which already comes in R). Then, I run a KNN model so I will know the flowers species based on the sepal and petal information. Later, someone brings me a flower which specie is unknown. How can I predict the flower specie?

This is the code I have so far:

```
# Load libraries
library(knitr)

### CHECK DATA
###############

kable(head(iris))

kable(summary(iris))

### NORMALIZE DATA
##################

dataNorm <- iris
dataNorm[, -5] <- scale(iris[, -5])

### DIVIDE DATA INTO TEST AND TRAIN
####################################
set.seed(1234)

# 70% train and 30% test
ind <- sample(2, nrow(dataNorm), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- dataNorm[ind==1,]
testData <- dataNorm[ind==2,]

### EXECUTE KNN
#################

# Load the class package
library("class")

# Execution of k-NN with k=3
KnnTestPrediction_k3 <- knn(trainData[,-5], testData[,-5],
                        trainData$Species, k=3, prob=TRUE)
```

First, let's suppose k=3 gives me the best model.
Now, I have a new flower with sepal.length=5, sepal.widht=4, petal.length=1.3, petal.width=0.35. How can I predict its specie based on my KNN model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @joran said, you need to create your observation, called in my case `mytest` and pass it to the `knn()`

```
mytest<- testData[1,-5]# creating format for my data
mytest[1,]<-c(5,4,1.3,0.35) # passing what you said

KnnTestPrediction_k3 <- knn(trainData[,-5], mytest,
                            trainData$Species, k=3, prob=TRUE)
KnnTestPrediction_k3
# [1] virginica
# attr(,"prob")
# [1] 1
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Please chaeck `?knn` to understand what the function is doing. Knn is just giving you the probability that the observation is classified as what the algortihm classifies it as.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I haven't thought about that lol... but really, many thanks!!!!!