# How to do prediction with knn classification in r

Tags: r

I tried to use KNN to predict the gender based on the industry and wage. This is my coding of doing it:

```
#normalize
norm <-function(x){((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}
mnorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(iwg[,-3], norm ))
summary(mnorm)

#training dataset
mstr <- mnorm[1:450,]
#test dataset
mste <- mnorm[451:569,]
library(class)
set.seed(12)
pred <- knn(mstr ,mste ,iwg[451:569,3],k=24)
g1 <- table(pred ,iwg[451:569,3])
g1

   pred      Man Woman
     Man      12    6
     Woman    30   71
```

May i know how can I do prediction with new values like annual_wage = 32000, industry = 1 (mean Tech) to predict the gender?

This is the summary and head of the data

```
#dataset before exclude dependent variable
 > head(iwg)
  SalaryInUSD        Industry Gender
1       55000               2  Woman
2       34000               1  Woman
3       62000               1  Woman
4       60000               1  Woman
5       62000               2    Man
6       50000               2    Man
> summary(mnorm)
  SalaryInUSD       Industry
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.2432   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.3566   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.3991   Mean   :0.2404  
 3rd Qu.:0.5210   3rd Qu.:0.5000  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000  

> head(mnorm) #after normalization
  SalaryInUSD        Industry
1   0.2261905             0.5
2   0.1071429             0.0
3   0.2658730             0.0
4   0.2545351             0.0
5   0.2658730             0.5
6   0.1978458             0.5
```

Comment: It's the 2nd question [the 1st was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73047600/incorrect-number-of-subscripts-on-matrix-in-r-when-i-tried-to-use-knn-to-predict) you ask today and you still haven't posted data.

Comment: I think it is duplicated .[How does one use KNN to predict something in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774898/how-does-one-use-knn-to-predict-something-in-r)

Comment: The code that you posted does not mention industry or wages. Your code does not match your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use KNN to predict something in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774898/how-does-one-use-knn-to-predict-something-in-r)

Comment: I delete the 1st question because there is something that i need to change.

Comment: I have tried this method https://stackoverflow.com/q/73047600/19558192 but it wont work as it came out this error:  Error in x[...] <- m : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix